# Узнать количество элементов в массиве

Tags: javascript

Как узнать количество элементов в массиве?

```
var arr = new Array({a: 123, b : 321 },{a: 123, b : 321 },{a: 123, b : 321 });
```

Нужно что бы вывело `3`.

Comment: В переменной может быть ровно один объект. Иногда он может быть массивом, но он все равно один.

Comment: А как назвать вот это колличество  {a: 123, b : 321 },{a: 123, b : 321 },{a: 123, b : 321 }; Элементы?

Comment: А разве массив не является объектом кстати?

Comment: @Нетглупыхвопросов В вашем коде в переменную присваивается только один из трех объектов. Массив - объект, но у него есть свойство length.
UDP: А, нет, ваш код невалидный.

Comment: @Save14 - скажите уже заодно - какой из трех

Comment: @Нетглупыхвопросов  `var arr = [{a: 123, b : 321 },{a: 123, b : 321 },{a: 123, b : 321 }]; console.log(arr.length);`

Comment: @Igor Код автора невалидный, на самом деле. Но если обернуть в скобки, то будет последний. `var arr = ({a: 123, b : 321 },{a: 123, b : 321 },{a: 123, b : 321 });`

Comment: не работает undefined

Comment: ...ровно один объект. **Иногда он может быть массивом**...

Comment: А посмотреть значение можно же так? alert( arr2[0].b); или как узнать значение данного объекта?

Comment: @Нетглупыхвопросов Одна из кнопок, появляющихся над текстом вопроса/ответа в режиме редактирования - "Фрагмент кода ...". Попробуйте.

Comment: Почему-то возвращает undefined ?(

Comment: @Нетглупыхвопросов «Дорогие учёные. У меня который год в подполе происходит подземный стук. Объясните, пожалуйста, как он происходит».

Answer (score 5):

```
console.log(Object.keys(arr).length);
```

Answer (score 4):

> не работает undefined

Где мой канделябр?

```js
var arr1 = [{
  a: 123,
  b: 321
}, {
  a: 123,
  b: 321
}, {
  a: 123,
  b: 321
}];
console.log(arr1.length);


var arr2 = new Array({
  a: 123,
  b: 321
}, {
  a: 123,
  b: 321
}, {
  a: 123,
  b: 321
});
console.log(arr2.length);
console.log(arr2[0].b);
```